# normally distributed mean 110cm variance $1050cm^2$. 2 plants chosen random. probability that the height is at least 1.5 times the height of the other

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Height of a certain plants are normally distributed with mean $110\text{ cm}$ and variance $1050\text{ cm}^2$.

> 2 plants are chosen at random. What is the probability that the height
> of one plant is at least 1.5 times the height of the other one?

This question Is the first I have seen doing past paper questions in statistics and probability its worth 7 marks I don't know how to solve it I know the answer is 0.346 but don't know how to get to it and what to I have no teacher as I am self studying so any help is much appreciated thank you

Comment: Are you sure about $0.346$?  I've got $0.029$...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe : 0.029? no, I found exactly the textbook solution...what was your reasoning?

Comment: My miscalculation ...

Answer (score 1):

If you select at random 2 plants it is self evident that one must be higher than the other, thus you have to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[X>1.5Y]+\mathbb{P}[Y>1.5X]=2\mathbb{P}[X>1.5Y]=2\mathbb{P}[X-1.5Y>0]=$$

$$=2\cdot\left[1-\Phi\left(\frac{55}{\sqrt{3412.5}}\right)\right]\approx2\times 0.173=0.346$$

This because

$$(X-1.5Y)\sim N(110-1.5\times110;1050+1.5^2\times1050)=N(-55;3412.5)$$

---

To understand the reasoning think at the following question:

> Selecting at random 2 plants what is the probability that one of the 2
> is higher than the other?

the answer is obviously 1, but you can calculate it

$$\mathbb{P}[X>Y]+\mathbb{P}[X<Y]=0.5+0.5=1$$

Comment: Thank youuu very much I understand everything but the understanding to the reasoning